# Attempting to have a choice of text color

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

I'm trying to make a C++ console application where users would be able to change the color of the text, but instead it cycles through each color and ends on the original. Here's what I have currently. Any help is appreciated.

```
while (strcmp(clrChoice, "nochange") != 0) {
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "gray") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 8");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "blue") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 1");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightblue") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 9");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "green") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 2");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightgreen") != 0) {
    system("COLOR A");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "aqua") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 3");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightaqua") != 0) {
    system("COLOR B");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "red") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 4");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightred") != 0) {
    system("COLOR C");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "purple") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 5");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightpurple") != 0) {
    system("COLOR D");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "yellow") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 6");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "lightyellow") != 0) {
    system("COLOR E");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "white") != 0) {
    system("COLOR 7");
    break;
}

while (strcmp(clrChoice, "brightwhite") != 0) {
    system("COLOR F");
    break;
}
```

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you need all these while loops?

Comment: @KirillKobelev They were "if" loops but it did the same thing so I tried changing them to while loops. I'm relatively new to c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the posted code the result will be always either color 7 or color E:

- For any string, different from "brightwhite" it will be F,
- For the "brightwhite" string it will be 7.

You may want this:

```
if (strcmp(clrChoice, "gray") == 0) {
    system("COLOR 8");
} else if (strcmp(clrChoice, "blue") == 0) {
    system("COLOR 1");
}
..........
```

Comment: I'll just come back to this idea when I have more knowledge on C++.